# Can I bathe my cockatoo with Dettol solution?

Tags: safety, cockatiels, bathing

Of course I'm not talking about an equal mixture of water and Dettol, just a cap full into the bucket. That's how I do it with my dogs and they've never had a problem. Speaking of dogs, I don't have bird shampoo. Can I use my dog shampoo on my cockatoo? The reason why I want to use Dettol is because I suspect my cockatoo has mites.

Comment: I don't have cockatoo experience, but I know there are dedicated mite-removal cleaning/bathing products for chickens, so I think you will have best outcome by using a bird-specific product when bathing.

Answer (score 4):

### What should I use?

Never use anything but **plain water** when bathing your bird, even shampoo's marketed for birds are not good.

Birds have a preen gland called the [uropygial gland](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/veterinary-science-and-veterinary-medicine/uropygial-gland) which secretes oils to keep feathers and skin healthy. Shampoos can remove these oils, leave soapy residues and dry their skin (which can ultimately lead to feather destructive behaviors).

### How Often?

Parrots should have access to a bath at minimum 3 times a week.

### What do I do if my parrot has mites?

Your first step is to go to your avian veterinarian to rule out mites, once a diagnosis is completed then the appropriate medication will be given. Typically for mites they are given an oral anti-parasitic.

If mites are the cause you will need to heavily disinfect their cages, I would throw out anything that is difficult to clean (i.e cotton ropes) to prevent reinfection.